# Concatenation two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two identical tables with the same number of rows but with different data

**Table 1:**

```
Name
---
A
B
C
```

**Table 2:**

```
Name
---
D
E
F
```

I need to join it like in one table.

```
Name1   Name2
----    -----
A       D
B       E
C       F
```

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: How do you match up the rows?

Comment: are these the only columns in the tables? How do you know whether `A` matches to `D` or `E` or `F`? Or do you just want to sort alphabetically and join based on the row number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no direct join then you could "manufacture" one.

i.e. given your example data:

```
WITH t1
  AS (SELECT name,
             rownum as rnum
        FROM table1
       ORDER BY name),
     t2
  AS (SELECT name,
             rownum as rnum
        FROM table2
       ORDER BY name)
SELECT *
  FROM t1
 INNER JOIN t2 USING (rnum);

RNUM NAME NAME_1
   1 A    D
   2 B    E
   3 C    F
```

EDIT: After Benoit's correct assertion I have added an ORDER BY (though you can order it by whatever criteria you need).

Comment: However you should note that the two subqueries `t1` and `t2` **should** include an ORDER BY clause because otherwise, there is **no guarantee** about the order in which rows are returned. There is no way to be sure that rows are returned in the same order that they were inserted otherwise.

Comment: Benoit, you are dead right. I should have added an order by clause, I'll edit it to put one in.

Comment: How can i  count record number instead of rownum because rownum return row number of the phisical table. I need to generate rownum for the select.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want but you should be able to get the number you require with an analytic function: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/AnalyticFunctions.php

Answer (score 1):

im not 100% sure what you are asking, wouldnt a normal union solve this?

```
select name1 from table1 union all select name2 from table2;
```

you could also create a view with that statement so that you can work with the data easier if you only have to read it.

EDIT: i think i misunderstood the question, if you want the result being two columns, you should join the tables

```
select t1.name1, t2.name2 from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.joinfield=t2.joinfield
```

where joinfield would be some column you use to match the rows of the 2 tables.

it sounds like there could be a better solution for your use case though, why do you have to do this?

Comment: I got one select 1 (tabe1) with start_times of period. select 2 (Table 2) is with end times of period. I need to marge it.

Comment: @AntonSirakov what other columns are in the tables? Surely there is something that identifies which period the data refers to?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table3 as select t1.field1, t2.field2 from table1 t1, table2 t2
```

Comment: This does a cross join and will return 9 rows instead of the required 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT table1.name, table2.name
INTO NewTable
FROM Table1,Table2